# Execute build file for Teamcity locally

Tags: deployment, msbuild, command, teamcity

I'm going through the tutorial from [this website](http://cgeers.com/2011/06/04/using-a-msbuild-script-in-teamcity/) which explains how to use a custom MSBuild script (*.build).

Because I'm new to this topic my question is how I can locally test the custom MSBuild script without Teamcity/VCS. Knows anyone the command for the command line? Or isn't that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's standard msbuild project file. You can test it by starting visual studio developer command prompt and executing msbuild from same directory as your `*.build` file.

```
msbuild filename.build /t:Target
```

where `filename.build` is your build file name, and `Target` is name of target defined inside build file. [More info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393573.aspx) about msbuild basic use.

Comment: thx. didn't know I have to use the visual studio developer command prompt